# multiple excerpt length and styles

Tags: excerpt, read-more

I am working on a site, which have many excerpt like text but with different style of read more or click here to read more with different length. is there a way i can make excerpt length according to what i mentioned above?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the uses of the More Tag? [Customizing the Read More](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More) shows many uses of variable length teasers with variable link phrases to read more.

For example, this markup entered in the Post editor will provide a link with `Read the rest of this story` in the anchor text.

```
<!--more Read the rest of this story -->
```

You can also use the Excerpt box in the Post Editor to create custom sections of text that summarize a story or article and then provides a link to the main article. That custom excerpt doesn't have to be part of the text of the post. It can be a teaser or long headline to entice the reader to click through to the post.